# Samsung Galaxy S III red light flashing rapidly upon plug in

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung, water-damage

**The short version:** I can't turn my *Samsung Galaxy S III* on, and when I plug it in, I get a rapid flashing red light, but no other response.

**The long version:** My *Samsung Galaxy S III* does not turn on. When I plug it in, the light on the top left flashes red. It does this rapidly, but it is not flickering, and stops after about a second or so. To give an indication as to how rapid it flashes, it goes about ten times in that second, and then just stops; that is, it flashes once every 100ms. Like I said, though, it is not flickering--the rate at which it flashes appears uniform.

**Background information:** This is following potential water damage. The device was put in a washing machine and I discovered it only after the cycle had completed. I removed the battery and the SIM card immediately and let it dry in front of a small fan for three days before attempting to plug it in. Due to concerns that the flashing red light might be the device's way of warning of a potential short-circuit, I have ***NOT*** left it plugged in for more than a few seconds at a time.

**The question:** What does this mean, exactly? Is this an obscure error code, and if so what does it mean? What approaches to salvaging this device apply in these circumstances, if any?

Comment: Since you mentioned water damage, have you tried the rice trick? (Oh, and a [source I found](http://www.droidista.com/2014/09/Samsung-Galaxy-S3-LED-Notification-Lights-Meaning.html) says that the blinking red light means a low battery, while blinking red light *while charging* means there's a problem with the battery/charger.)

Comment: Is a (potential) short circuit truly such a bad thing on a low-voltage (5-volt) device such as a cellphone?